# cohomology of orbit space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Let $T^p=S^1\times\cdots \times S^1$ be the $p$-dimensional torus. 
Then $$H^*(T^p;\mathbb{Z}_p)=\otimes_pH^*(S^1;\mathbb{Z}_p)=\otimes_p\Lambda_{\mathbb{Z}_p}[a].$$ Here $|a|=1$.

Let $S_p$ be the permutation group of order $p$. Let $S_p$ act on $T^p$ by permuting the coordinates $$\sigma\in S_p: T^p\to T^p,$$ $$(x_1,\cdots,x_p)\mapsto (x_{\sigma(1)},\cdots,x_{\sigma(p)}).$$

How to get $$H^*(T^p/S_p;\mathbb{Z}_p)?$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the Cartan-Leray spectral sequence and equivariant cohomology? There's at least a spectral sequence that computes at least $H^*$ as a graded vector space (ignoring the cup product). The major complication is that your $S_p$ action isn't free, but most of the stabilizers are of order prime to $p$. Working through the computation over $\mathbb{Q}$ (where the stabilizers all contribute nothing because they're finite) might be helpful.

Comment: Dear Professor Anomaly, thanks! If the action is free for another space, does Cartan-Leray spectral sequence have some cohomology version that can study cup product?

Comment: I don't think there's one that gives it to you automatically (just from the way spectral sequences work), but the typical approach is to construct a suitable fibration, get lucky enough that its spectral sequence abuts quickly, and reconstruct the cup product structure from those of the fiber and base; see Chapter 5 of "A User's Guide to Spectral Sequences" for a few examples worked out in detail. I think the product structure on $T^p$ is simple enough that you can probably do something similar here.